# AngularJS - uglify angular.module

Tags: angularjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

```
angular.module('myApplication').factory('myService', [function() {
    return {
        name: 'name'
    };
}]);
```

When I tried to inject above service in my controller.

```
myApplication.controller('myController', [ 'myService',  function(myService) {}]);
```

It gives me below error after uglifying it:

Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: myServiceProvider <- myService <- myController

Comment: You need 

var myApplication=angular.module('myApplication');

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module  The angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules.  I am retriving module through angular.module('myApplication'), instread of defining var myApplication.

Comment: Your code looks right, check the minified file and see if it contains the service. You may be targeting wrong source files and your service might bee missing from minified version. Or post the grunt task config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be using same angular module.

```
angular.module('myApplication', []); //inject dependency in [] if anything there

angular.module('myApplication').factory('myService', [function() {
    return {
        name: 'name'
    };
}]);

angular.module('myApplication').controller('myController', ['myService',
    function(myService) {
        //controller code here
    }
]);
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/YLnH5k15VLeweri0qyTM?p=preview)

Comment: @Nitul any errror in console? could you please check it?

Comment: It is giving me same erorr as I mentioned in question.

Comment: @Nitul check I have added plunkr